Not able to run pytest
Can someone help me. I have installed pytest however when I try to run it from command line, it does not work. See pic.
I read documentation but it just says to use the keyword pytest followed by name of the file.

Read the error. There isn't a recognized command named pytest, likely because you installed in in a different directory.

If pytest has been installed correctly, you would just run pytest, not py pytest (pytest isn't a file in your current directory, so that won't work). You can try py -m pytest, which will work as long as you haven't switched to a new virtual environment from the one in which it was installed.
